# What are the three parts of a GLM from R code?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I have 2 similar models in R and I'm not sure if they follow the same pattern. The code is as follows

M1 <- glm(weight ~ age+sex, family = "gaussian")

M2 <- glm(weight ~ age*sex, family = "gaussian")

As I understand it they would have a Normal random part and an identity link function, but what is the systematic of the GLM? And are the three parts the same for each model?

I realise these models may not need to take a GLM however I am trying to understand how to work out the three parts of a GLM from code in R.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "3 parts" But the difference between your models is in the predictors. M1 uses only age and sex to predict weight. M2 also fits an interaction i.e. the effect of age is different between the sexes.

Comment: The three parts I'm referring to is the random part, systematic part and link function of a GLM

Comment: The part between "glm(" and "family" is the "systematic part" (the model for the linear predictor).

Answer (score 1):

The "systematic part" of the model is the linear predictor (`age+sex` for the first model and `age*sex` for the second) together with the link function that connects the linear predictor to the fitted values (the identity function is the default for the Gaussian family).
The "random part" of the model is the probability family (Gaussian in this case).